# Finding values in a Dataframe in Python that follow a trend

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe which contains information of compressors as follows:

The Dataframe of compressors:

[image]

I would like to know the loading time of each of the compressors. It can be computed by finding an occurrence of a set point (say 32000) after the most recent value of 0 in the ACTIVEPOWER column of the respective compressor and counting the number of rows between them (as each row represents a minute). How can I achieve this operation in pandas in python?

```
d1 = {'ACTIVEPOWER_1': [23000, 34000 , 45000, 0, 34000, 32000, 132000, 45000, 30000, 0, 32000, 132000]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
```

If the input is  the above dataframe (df1) ,then the output should look something like df2 given below

```
d2 = {'Loading Times': [ 3, 2]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read: **[mcve]**. In particular, please show us your desired output from the input.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @jpp I've given an example of what the inputs and outputs would look like.

Comment: @Anne I was thinking about filters but can't seem to figure out how I can achieve this result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'ACTIVEPOWER_1': [23000, 34000 , 45000, 0, 34000, 32000,
                        132000, 45000, 30000, 0, 32000, 132000 , 0]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

start = df1.loc[df1['ACTIVEPOWER_1']==0].index
end = df1.loc[df1['ACTIVEPOWER_1']==32000].index

res = pd.DataFrame({'Loading Times': [j-i+1 for i, j in zip(start, end)]})

#    Loading Times
# 0              3
# 1              2
```

Comment: thanks a lot for an approach. However I think this only works when the number of 0s is equal to the number of setpoints. Suppose the dataframe was [23000, 34000 , 45000, 0, 34000, 32000,
                        132000, 45000, 30000, 0, 32000, 132000 , 0]  it would throw an error.